# Hibernate handle long 0 value instead of NULL in ManyToOne relations

Tags: java, hibernate, null, zero

I use Hibernate to access to a legacy DB. For some tables the parent-child reference integrity is not enforced, and the `long` 0 value is used instead of NULL for some "parent" columns in child tables to denote "no parent".

I still want to use these relations in `@ManyToOne` and `@OneToMany` fields, but get `EntityNotFound` error since the 0 value does not correspond to any record in master table.

What are my options?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the [`NotFound`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/annotations/NotFound.html) annotation:

```
@NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
```

See http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#mapping-declaration-manytoone

Comment: This workarounds my problem. But I still want Hibernate to force reference integrity for all non-zero key values.

Comment: Hibernate doesn't force reference integrity. The database does. A foreign key constraint should exist, but it's of course impossible due to these 0-valued rows. Hibernate won't be able to magically enforce referential integrity that even the database is unable to enforce. If you map this column as an association, I don't see how you could create a non-zero value pointing to nothing, though.

Comment: This is a legacy DB with undocumented scheme, and these reference are maintained by a proprietary software. All I know at the moment is that 0 values are allowed as keys instead usual NULLs. I suppose reference integrity still exists for these relations and is maintained by the proprietary software, but I want to be reported immediately if my assumption is wrong.

Comment: As I said, if you store an existing parent in your child, Hibernate will of course use the parent ID to populate the column. So I don't see how you could break referential integrity.

Comment: The proprietary software, not me, can potentially break the code. I suspect this since I don't know why the authors decided not to force reference integrity for some columns. BTW, I've tried to add the @NotFound annotation, but it seems Hibernate ignores it (in the AnnotationBinder.processElementAnnotations() method). May be, the Hibernate annotations, as opposed to JPA annotations, must be explicitly enabled?

Comment: So you would like Hibernate to throw an exception for all incorrect values except 0. Is that right? If so, I don't have an answer. But it looks like a strange requirement to me. Why not fixing the buggy software?

Comment: Yes, you get me right, I want Hibernate throw an exception. The software mentioned is from a big software company, there is no source code, and I suspect the authors think of it as a feature, but not a bug anyway. Also the @NotFound annotation was silently ignored since the NotFound class was not found in my environment.

Comment: Also you might be omitting data inconsistencies if a object with id is missing (+1 because is a good solution to your problem)

Comment: @Vladimir how did you overcome this issue? I need to resolve a similar kind of issue of a legacy code to persist a record in child table with value 0 instead of Null when no parent exists.

Comment: @malware I did not :-(

Answer (score 2):

Instead of the `@JoinColumn` could be used `@JoinFormula`. Like this

```
@JoinFormula(value="CASE the0isNullColumn"
             + " WHEN 0"
             + " THEN NULL"
             + " ELSE the0isNullColumn"
             + " END")
```

The expression means we check the column and if it's 0 return NULL. Then hibernate doesn't search for the related entity.

Answer (score 0):

You can map it to `java.lang.Long` which default value is null. Or you can use a `@PostLoad` and null it if `0`. You can also use a `@Formula` and ignore `0`.

The `@Formula` as written in their [documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-column) can be used to `join conditions`.

Since I don't know your data model providing a valid example is tricky. Try with:

```
id_fk is not null or id_fk <> 0
```

block.

If it does not suit your needs you can write you own [Query loader](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/reference/en-US/html/querysql.html#querysql-load)

If you are using some sort of logging enable the `show_sql` property. And add to your config the `org.hibernate.sql` `DEBUG`.

Comment: @Formula requires a valid SQL expression. Can you provide the expression to replace 0 by NULL?

Comment: Mapping fields to java.lang.Long is not what I need. I need these fields mapped to the entity class as @ManyToOne.

Comment: I just can't make JoinColumnOrFormula working. I placed a bug report here https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/HHH-6811. I will try Loader annotation if I run out of other options.

Comment: enable the log and paste the sql